# how to prevent submitting a form by enter and also keep enable enter for other field like search in grid etc

Tags: javascript

I have tried all methods like `onkeydown="return !(event.keyCode==13)"` and `onsubmit="return false;"` inside form tag but these are stopping enter key to work for rest of the form as well.

All i want is let enter key enable for rest of the form but my form only get submitted when i click a particular button with class/id. It would be better if the solution is in core javascript or prototype.js library.

Comment: it would be best if you shared your code.

Comment: not clear where you want to prevent it when you say it needs to work in the rest of the form. Provide [mcve] You haven't shown us any part of a form

Answer (score 1):

In case of you can't run the snippet, `https://jsfiddle.net/begpv4et/`

```js
x.addEventListener("keypress",function stopThatCrazyActionPlease(e) {
if (e.keyCode === 13) {
e.preventDefault();
}
})
// replace x with your form's ID
```

```html
<form action="action_page.php" id="x">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<!-- This form is not affected because of different id -->
<form action="action_page.php" id="y">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I set the ID of the first form to `x` so I can access it in DOM later.

Then, I listen for an event called `keypress`. The name says it all.

The line `e.keyCode === 13` means if the user pressed ENTER, I will prevent the default behaviour : submit the form `e.preventDefault()`.

You will see that line of code very often when you listen to events like `ENTER` pressed, `onClick`, `onHover`, et cetera.

Comment: I haven't voted, but will say that an answer that includes a description of what is being done and how the objective is achieved are received more favourably than those that simply provide code and no explanation. Many believe good code should be self-documenting, let this not be a deterrent to making your answers accessible and useful for the less experienced, by way of explicit commentary!

Comment: That makes for a better answer, bravo.

Comment: A pleasure. It's what we're all here for after all - trading in the precious resource known as help.

Comment: I guess why you got a downvote (but personnally I didn't do it): it's because your solution doesn't work! Please look a my answer which explains why.

Comment: Run the fiddle, please

Answer (score 0):

The @Learn How To Be Transparent's answer doesn't solve the problem, since it merely prevents {Enter} key to work, even as it's pure entry action.

This becomes clear if we replace one of the `<input>`'s by `<textarea>` in its snippet.
Here we can see that striking {Enter} doesn't insert a line-break in the 1st form (the one which is monitored by the `keypress` event):

```js
x.addEventListener("keypress",function(e) {
if (e.keyCode === 13) {
e.preventDefault();
}
})
// replace x with your form's ID
```

```html
<form action="action_page.php" id="x">
  First name:<br>
  <textarea>Mickey</textarea>
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<!-- This form is not affected because of different id -->
<form action="action_page.php" id="y">
  First name:<br>
  <textarea>Mickey</textarea>
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

So another approach must be used to achieve what the OP looks for.

A simple way may be like this:

1. Use `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"` for the `<input>` or `<button>` dedicated to the form submission: so striking {Enter} key has no effect upon submission, and can be freely used as entry part everywhere.
2. Then to have a mean for the form to be submitted, attach an `onclick` event to this button, and launch form submission in its handler.

Here is a working example.
In order to clearly show its work, I replaced `form.submit()` by an `alert()`:

```js
submit_button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  // here is the real code for form submission:
  // e.target.form.submit();
  // currently replaced by:
  alert('Form submission now');
});
```

```html
<form action="action_page.php" id="x">
  First name:<br>
  <textarea>Mickey</textarea>
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input id="submit_button" type="button" value="Submit">
</form>
```